# How to differentiate between audio 3gp file and video 3gp file

Tags: android, audio, video

I have some `audio 3gp file` and `video 3gp file` .I need only video 3gp file but my query returning me both audio and video file.`My Api level is`**8**

Here is my query

```
 String[] data = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
 Cursor vid_cursor=this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,data, null, null, null);
```

I can filter it by checking the height, only video will return height as it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333004/how-to-differentiate-between-3gp-audio-and-3gp-video) but I don't want to calculate height everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may helps you

```
String[] data = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
         Cursor vid_cursor=this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,data, MediaStore.Video.Media.HEIGHT+">0", null, null);
```

This will work with API level 16 and onward.

Update :for lower version (We need to check content type like this)

```
ursor vid_cursor=this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,data, MediaStore.Video.Media.CONTENT_TYPE +" like %video%", null, null);
```

Comment: sorry this will work with api level 16 onward. Give me 5 min seeing for alternative.

Comment: mime type returns format like mp4 ,3gpp etc therefore ur query is not working

Comment: Hi I just update the post. We need to check content_type rather mime_type try this and let me know.